# c++ appending to string

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, append

Is there an easy way to append an integer to a string?

I have a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
  for (int g = 0; g < word.length(); g++) {
    if (text[i] == word[g]) {
      kodas.append(g);
    }
  }
}
```

and I need to get the index of the array which is equal, and the index of course is an integer type. But as I do this I get an error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]|
```

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What would this achieve? You'd end up with a meaningless concatenate of decimal numerals...

Comment: It's not useful to append an integer to a string, just like it's not useful to append a passenger to a train. What you want is to _write out_ an integer to the end of a string. This indicates you rather want to use a `stringstream` rather than `string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use stringstream if you are working with std::strings: `#include <sstream>`

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
string oldString = "old";
int toAppend = 5;
stringstream ss(toAppend);
string newString = oldString + ss.str();
```

`newString` will be `"old5"`

Comment: I recommend `stringstream ss(oldString);` and then just `ss.str()` is the result.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

You can, for example:

- use the `itoa` function that converts integers into strings
- make your `kodas` an `ostringstream` and "write" into it as you would to `cout`: `kodas << g`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is like so:

```
if (kodas.empty()) { kodas += ' '; }
kodas += std::to_string(g);
```

If you don't have C++11, use `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(g)` instead.

Failing everything, you can do something terrible like this:

```
kodas += static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << g).str();
```

Comment: @d33tah: It's not bad, it just looks hideous.

Answer (score 0):

itoa(), its the into to alpha function, should help you out. sprintf or vsprintf works too if you want to

Comment: Suggesting `vsprintf` rather than `vsnprintf` is borderline criminal! Are you a botnet?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of formatting a number as a string in C++, including [`sprintf()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sprintf.3.html), [`boost:lexical_cast()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html), and others. See [The String Formatters of Manor Farm](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) for a good comparison and additional suggestions. In addition, C++11 has `std::to_string`. Your compiler may or may not have it yet.